# Make getElementText go through loop

Tags: r, loops, rselenium

I used RSelenium package for web scraping

my code :

```
library(RSelenium)
driver <- rsDriver(port=4444L,browser="chrome")
remote_driver <- driver$client
remote_driver$open()
remote_driver$navigate("https://www.amazon.in/b/?_encoding=UTF8&node=1389401031&ref_=sv_top_elec_mega_1")
one<-remote_driver$findElement(using = "class", value="crwTitle")
k<- one$getElementText()
```

it works but it returns only one record as shown here

the output of k :

```
[1] "Samsung Galaxy M30 (Gradation Blue, 4+64 GB)"
```

I tried to create a loop

```
gettx <- lapply(one,function(one) {
  one$getElementText()
})
```

but I got this error

```
Error in one$getElementText : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

what I expect is

```
Samsung Galaxy M30 (Gradation Blue, 4+64 GB)
Samsung Galaxy M20 (Ocean Blue, 4+64GB)
Redmi 6A (Black, 2GB RAM, 16GB Storage)

...........etc
```

I mean I need to return all elements have the same class.

any help?

Comment: try: `one<-remote_driver$findElements(using = "class", value="crwTitle")` and then you should be able to loop through it.

Comment: does it work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
remDr$navigate("https://www.amazon.in/b/?_encoding=
                UTF8&node=1389401031&ref_=sv_top_elec_mega_1")
elems <- remDr$findElements(using = "class", value="crwTitle")

lapply(elems, function(elem) {
  elem$getElementText()
})
```

Note that `remDr$findElement()` just finds a single element while `remDr$findElements()` finds a list of elements.